# Is there a way to get the deleted directory items from Microsoft Graph API using the C# SDK?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Theres a doc page describing the exact thing that I want to do

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directory-deleteditems-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

However, the suggested way to retrieve this data in C# is

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var group = await graphClient.Directory.DeletedItems
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

I tried using this and got a bad request error due to not specifying the type of item to view. I cant seem to find a way to specify this in the C# SDK.

for reference, this is how it's done in the Java SDK

```
IGroupCollectionPage group = graphClient.directory().deletedItems().microsoft.graph.group()
    .buildRequest()
    .get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a similar issue raised in [Github](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/10080) and will update you accordingly

For a workaround, you can use the below code

```
 var deletedGroupReq = await graphClient.Directory.DeletedItems["microsoft.graph.group"]
                        .Request()
                        .Select("DisplayName,DeletedDateTime")
                        .GetAsync();
                    var deletedGroups = graphClient.HttpProvider.Serializer.DeserializeObject<IGraphServiceGroupsCollectionPage>(deletedGroupReq.AdditionalData["value"].ToString());
    
                    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(deletedGroups));
```

Comment: Has this workaround stopped working? I had used this effectively for a bit, but recently this has started resulting in a null reference exception

Answer (score 0):

According to the code from the issue [.NET example for deleteditems seems to be wrong](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/10280) I ended up with the following code:

```
async Task<List<DirectoryObject>> ExecuteMsGraphHttpCallForDeletedObjects(string directoryObjectType)
{
    var all = new List<DirectoryObject>();

    var groupItemsUrl = graphClient.Directory.DeletedItems.AppendSegmentToRequestUrl(directoryObjectType);
    var currentSet = await (new DirectoryDeletedItemsCollectionRequestBuilder(groupItemsUrl, graphClient)).Request().GetAsync();

    while (currentSet.Count > 0)
    {
        all.AddRange(currentSet.CurrentPage);

        if (currentSet.NextPageRequest != null)
        {
            currentSet = await currentSet.NextPageRequest.GetAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return all;
}
```